# react and node js - consultation

Tags: node.js, reactjs

this is more of a question in free flow rather than code examples, because I need some guidance before I proceed with my project.

I did a quick udemy course on node, express, react and mongo back in March. The course was roughly about a month long. My effort was to start a project for a squash league community that I own in my city. Before starting the project, I did my research and decided to go with Node, express and mongo(mongoose). After 3 months, I am done with my project and pretty proud :).

While working along, I also had some ideas on how to add some social media aspects to my web app. So as Phase 2 I want to build that out.

Now the question. REACT obviously is a much better tool to build the social media website. So I was thinking to learn REACT a little more and then use it to build the social media aspect of my web app.
Is this a good approach? All the front ends of my app currently are built using HTML/css, node and ejs.

I basically dont want to rework on anything that I have built so far.

I am just trying to ask the experts if this approach is viable or will I run into any issues later. Please guide.